# is there a way to see which contributor changed exactly which line in github?

Tags: git, github

in github, sometimes there are multiple contributors. 
Let's say programmer A made a PR. 
programmer B reviewed it and made some changes.
after that, programmer C reviewed it and make some other changes.

Is there a way to see which line is changed by A, or B or C?

Comment: Try the "blame" command, you can use it both on github (view a file, look for the Blame button just above and to the right of the file), or use the local `git blame A` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

look for the Blame button when viewing the particular file.